# Keep responsive/fluid grid contents contained within viewport size at all times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I want to create a responsive/fluid grid which has 2 rows of content `.tier1` and `.tier2`. The contents should always fit inside the dimensions of the viewport with `.tier1` occupying 60% of the height and `.tier2` the remaining 40%. At the moment I'm not sure what the best approach to this is, using javascript I could keep an eye on the viewport dimensions and set a height so that the `.tier` containers applied % heights take effect but I was wondering if I can just do this using CSS?

**CSS**

```
.content1 {
    height: 60%;
}
.content2 {
    height: 40%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tier">
        <div class="content content1">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tier">
        <div class="content content2">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/dedede/fff">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/EK6QT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support ([CanIUse... reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)), you could always introduce CSS3 [Viewport Relative Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

So for your example, rather than using `%`, simply use `vh`:

```css
.content1 {
    height: 60vh;
}
.content2 {
    height: 40vh;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EK6QT/2/).

If you want more in-depth detail surrounding what these are, I have another answer here which discusses these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1317805

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've been trying to implement the units in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V2YZA/1/ but my problem is that the heights are now set and don't scale up or down nicely, instead they remain at the set height of 60 or 30 etc?

Comment: like scaling up or down the main large black area always stays at the same height which is 290px for me

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this is scaling fine for me if I resize the JSFiddle result area. Your `height:x%` declarations will not work as there is nothing for them to scale to - their containers would also need absolute heights or heights relative to absolute heights. Changing these to `px` values gives a noticeable change.

Comment: my problem is i dont get that fluid feel when i resize down as the height doesnt seem to reduce based on the viewport size, height seems to stay fixed at a certain size